# 80s or 90s children's movie about magic dying

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

I'm looking for the title of a children's movie from the 80s or 90s.

The premise: a kid goes into a magic shop and ends up having to save the magic realm. People have stopped believing in magic and everything that is magical is slowly dying, including the owner of the magic shop, a human/troll named Ophodi (not sure of the spelling). There is a scene where the owner of the magic shop is laying on the ground coughing because magic is being forgotten.

It's a kind of darker kids’ movie.

This one is close with the type of filming.  But still lacks the character and scenes that I remember.

Answer (score 3):

[The Magic Shop (1982)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457051/)

> A father and son enter a magic shop that may contain real magic.
>
> Director: Ian Emes Writers: H.G. Wells (short story), Ian Emes
>   (adaptation) Stars: Karl Johnson, Ron Cook, Paul Erangey

Comment: Unfortunately the movie I'm thinking of is a children's movie, not horror.  ☹️

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [*The Neverending Story*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0088323/) (1984).

Comment: Could you [edit] to expand on this for how it matches?

Comment: This unfortunately only matches in the broad strokes - that of a magic land that's dying.  The book, the store, the owner, none of the rest of it matches.